# Create custom query with RTK query

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I need to get a signature first by a post request, then use it in another query (get request) as a custom query:

```
export const useSignatureCustomQuery = (arg: string) => {
 
  const [getSignature] = useGetSignatureKeyMutation();
  const signature = getSignature({
    url: `${REST_END_POINTS.GET_SIGNATURE}`,
  })
    .unwrap()
    .then((res) => res.data.attributes.signature);

  const data = useFetchDataQuery(arg, {
    skip: !signature ,
  });

  return { data };
};
```

But when I want to use the custom query as below,

```
const { data: query } = useSignatureCustomQuery(
    REST_END_POINTS.POSITION_INFORMATION,
    !!positions
  );
```

I'm receiving this error:

> Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Promise<{ data: UseQueryHookResult<QueryDefinition<string, BaseQueryFn<string | FetchArgs, unknown, FetchBaseQueryError, {} & RetryOptions, FetchBaseQueryMeta>,

What is wrong with the code?

Comment: `useSignatureCustomQuery` is a synchronous function and `getSignature` starts an asynchronous Promise-chain, `signature` can only ever be a Promise object when passed to `useFetchDataQuery`. Are you trying to pass the resolved `res.data.attributes.signature` value to `useFetchDataQuery`? I think this is what @phry says in less words.

Answer (score 1):

Your mutation would execute on every render, and your `getSignature` function would return a promise.

You actually do not need a mutation for a POST request - use a query instead.

```js
  const res = useGetSignatureKeyQuery();
  const data = useFetchDataQuery(arg, {
    skip: !res.data?.attributes.signature,
  });
```

Comment: but i'm forced to use post query for getting the signature

Comment: @ phry,  there is no way to do this with RTK query something like using axios ?

result1 = axios.post (,,,,)
result2 = axios.get(result1)

Comment: What do you mean by "forced to use post query for getting the signature"? Do you only want this to trigger when you execute the trigger function? Because your code was triggering that on every single render.